# Wordpress + Constant Contact PHP SDK include path

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, constantcontact

I'm current trying to implement the Constant Contact PHP sdk into a wordpress site. Ask part of the SDK you have to include some core PHP files in order for the email code to work. If those files aren't found, the page dies with no PHP error. Currently I have the folder called "src" 9their naming convention not mine) in the root of the site's theme (/wp-content/themes/mytheme/src...).

Here is the email form code that calls the files:

```
<?php
// require the autoloader
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/src/Ctct/autoload.php');

use Ctct\ConstantContact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\ContactList;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\EmailAddress;
use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;

// Enter your Constant Contact APIKEY and ACCESS_TOKEN
define("APIKEY", "XXXXXX");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "XXXXXX");

$cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);

// attempt to fetch lists in the account, catching any exceptions and printing the errors to screen
try {
    $lists = $cc->getLists(ACCESS_TOKEN);
} catch (CtctException $ex) {
    foreach ($ex->getErrors() as $error) {
        print_r($error);
    }
}

// check if the form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 1) {
    $action = "Getting Contact By Email Address";
    try {
        // check to see if a contact with the email addess already exists in the account
        $response = $cc->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $_POST['email']);

        // create a new contact if one does not exist
        if (empty($response->results)) {
            $action = "Creating Contact";

            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->addEmail($_POST['email']);
            $contact->addList($_POST['list']);
            $contact->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $contact->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

            /*
             * The third parameter of addContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell Constant
             * Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
             * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
             *
             * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
             */
            $returnContact = $cc->addContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, false);

            // update the existing contact if address already existed
        } else {
            $action = "Updating Contact";

            $contact = $response->results[0];
            $contact->addList($_POST['list']);
            $contact->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $contact->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

            /*
             * The third parameter of updateContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell
             * Constant Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
             * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
             *
             * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
             */
            $returnContact = $cc->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, false);
        }

        // catch any exceptions thrown during the process and print the errors to screen
    } catch (CtctException $ex) {
        echo '<span class="label label-important">Error ' . $action . '</span>';
        echo '<div class="container alert-error"><pre class="failure-pre">';
        print_r($ex->getErrors());
        echo '</pre></div>';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

autoload.php is available where it should be at http://www.thedaileymethod.com/_main_site/wp-content/themes/dailey-method/src/Ctct/autoload.php which is what I thought I called in the PHP file, but the page keeps on breaking for me.

Do I have the require_once path incorrect?

EDIT:

When the for code is loaded, the page 500 errors. When I remove the form code, that error goes away and the page loads fine. Nothing nothing in the log from a PHP error standpoint.

Comment: do you have php errors turned on? require_once will return a fatal error if not found.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the issue by moving the PHP form code into our of the header of the site and into the template area. It now functions properly. Still not sure why it didn't work in the header, but problem solved for now.

Comment: Been trying to get this working my self this morning. It seems that no matter what route I take that the class ConstantContact is not available, and these 'use' statements are causing errors left and right. I have met the minimum requirements, so not entirely sure whats going wrong. This API has been one of the most challenging to get integrated...

Comment: EHerman here is my final file that I ended up with. The src folder is the the active theme.

http://cloud.two-bird.com/code/3T311G1H1R0Q

Answer (score 0):

Remove statements with use `use` keyword and change

```
$cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);
```

to

```
$cc = new \Ctct\ConstantContact(APIKEY);
```